# Set Up Equipment

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs, transitivity

According this [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/set_1): (at def 2 of "*set <something> up*), to *set up* a piece of equipment is to make it ready for use.  But then there is this [piece](http://online.wsj.com/articles/hong-kong-government-seeks-to-wait-out-protesters-1412149487):

> As on other days, numbers shrank in the midday heat and swelled again as evening approached. Toward evening, an impromptu funk band ***set up in the occupied Causeway Bay district***, performing Beatles songs.

Is something missing between "*set up*" and "*in the occupied Causeway Bay district*"?  Would "*set up* ***equipment*** *in the occupied Causeway Bay district*" be better?

Comment: It would be possible, but not 'better'. The most important thing that a band sets up for a performance is the band members themselves.

Comment: @StoneyB  So, the verb phrase "set up" does not require an object noun and could be used intransitively

Comment: Exactly. In fact, the opposite of *set up* is *strike*, and it is used the same way, both transitively and intransitively.

Comment: Well, sometimes "strike" is the opposite of "set up". Other times "tear down" or "put away" are more apt.  And then there's "strike up the band"!!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's correct as is. Here, 'set up' refers to the band itself. Optionally, you could say:

> Toward evening, an impromptu funk band set **itself** up in the occupied Causeway Bay district.

Generally, though, if you have "[entity] set up in [location]", it's widely assumed to mean that the entity (usually a business or performance) has started doing whatever it does at that location, no further explanation necessary.